# Sequelize ORM query on JsonB array in PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, jsonb

How can I use some matching conditions and logical operations(**lt**, **et**, **gte** etc.) on Jsonb array of objects (**[{...}, {...}]**) in PostgreSQL using Sequelize ORM.

**TableName:** calls

| id | direction | metaData |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | inbound | [{...}, {...}] |
| 2 | outbound | [{...}, {...}] |

metaData:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "audioUrl": "https://xyz.wav",
    "duration": 136,
    "agentName": "Ext 204",
    "calledNumber": "123456789",
    "callingNumber": "987654321",
    "startedAt": "2020-08-31 5:07:00",
    "endedAt": "2020-08-31 11:07:20",
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "audioUrl": "https://abc.wav",
    "duration": 140,
    "agentName": "Ext 210",
    "calledNumber": "123456789",
    "callingNumber": "987654321",
    "startedAt": "2020-08-31 10:07:00",
    "endedAt": "2020-08-31 10:09:20",
}]
```

I want to search for data from the table base on the metaData conditions using Sequelize ORM.
**Example 1:** fetch all rows where agentName='Ext 204' AND duration >= 136

**Example 2:** fetch all rows where agentName='Ext 204' AND startedAt >= '2020-08-31 10:07:00'

**My model query:**

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const resp = await callModel.findAll({
      attributes: ['id', 'direction'], // table columns
      where: {
            metaData: { // jsonB column
                [Op.contains]: [
                    {agentName: 'Ext 204'},
                ],
            },
        },
    });
```

The above model search call executes following query:

```
SELECT "id", "direction" FROM "calls" AS "calls" WHERE "calls"."metaData" @> '[{"agentName":"Ext 205"}]';
```

**My Attempt:** which is not working

```
callModel.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'direction'], // table columns
        where: {
            metaData: { // metaData
                [Op.and]: [
                    {
                        [Op.contains]: [
                            {agentName: 'Ext 204'},
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        duration: {
                            [Op.lt]: 140
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
        },
    });
```

Resultant query:

```
SELECT "id", "direction" FROM "calls" AS "calls" WHERE ("calls"."metaData" @> '[{"agentName":"Ext 205"}]' AND CAST(("calls"."metaData"#>>'{duration}') AS DOUBLE PRECISION) < 140);
```

**Required:** Unable to add some more conditions as **duration < 140**

Comment: Could you clarify your example? Do you mean "...rows where **any** object within `metaData` match the conditions" or "fetch rows where **all** objects in `metaData` matches"?

Comment: @Emma: Thanks for taking interest in this problem.
Psuedo Code:

SELECT * FROM calls WHERE calls.direction = 'outbound' and calls.metaData.duration > 136;

Comment: in your example `metaData`, `duration > 136` only matches for `metaData.id=2` and not for `metaData.id=1`, in this case do you want this record (`id=2, direction=outbound`) to return?

Comment: Yes but I'm unable to add logical operations (>, <, <= etc) in JsonB field on the duration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are querying against the JSONB field, the regular logical operations won't work.

For instance, you used `Op.contains` in your example and this is composed as `"calls"."metaData" @> ...` which `@>` is a special operator for JSON field.

You can find more JSON operators here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html

And for greater than operation, you can use `@@` operator to check elements within the array. As far as I know, Sequelize do not have support for this `@@` operations, I use `literal` SQL.

```js
where: {
  [Op.and]: [
    {
      metaData: {
        [Op.contains]: [
          {agentName: 'Ext 204'},
        ],
      }
    },
    Sequelize.literal(`"calls"."metaData" @@ '$[*].duration >= 136'`)
  ]
}
```

This will return the entire records (including all elements in metaData) if **any** elements within the `metaData` matches the condition.

Comment: You're right, I also added Sequelize.literal() method to apply the condition, I didn't use logical operation yet but applied like_regix.
Thanks for your answer