# How do i query a postgres jsonb field?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

```
[
    {
        "id": 397221,
        "user": {
            "id": "004e6cfc",
            "name": "foo",
            "image": null,
            "userId": 18856,
            "userModel": "nurse"
        },
        "unreadCount": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 397220,
        "user": {
            "id": "9752cef3",
            "name": "michy",
            "image": null,
            "userId": 649,
            "userModel": "facility"
        },
        "unreadCount": 0
    }
]
```

The data above is the data on the member column of a user table, how do I query the userId=649 with sequelize or Postgresql raw query of sequelize won't work?

This is a Postgres database.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: i'm using postgres

Comment: What is the result you want? And do you want a SQL solution or a JavaScript solution?

Comment: I'm using sequelize ORM, so i guess a javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple value equality in 1 layer object in JSONB, you can write query as

```js
await db.User.findAll({
  where: {
    user: {   // column name
      userId: 649   // key name within the JSONB column
    }
  }
})
```

If you have more complicated JSONB such as an array or complex filtering condition, you can check [Sequelize ORM query on JsonB array in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74025761/sequelize-orm-query-on-jsonb-array-in-postgresql/74070816#74070816)